# CSS properties not changing when using custom property variables

Tags: javascript, css

I'm pretty new to CSS, and I'm trying to make a button that can change width and height with a slider, while testing if I could get CSS variables working with JS, I couldn't

Javascript:

```
document.documentElement.style.cssText = "--zoom-button-width: 300"
```

CSS:

```
.zoomButton1 { width: var(--zoom-button-width); }
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618941/8620333 (you will find how to adjust CSS variables using JS/jquery

Comment: Your value needs a unit. `300` what? 300 pixels? 300 miles?

Comment: Yeah, after posting this, I went to go test some things, and I tried both 
"--zoom-button-width: 300px" and "width: var(--zoom-button-width)px;" and neither of those worked

Comment: related if you want to use uniteless properties: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57666183/8620333

Answer (score 1):

The magical line:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--zoom-button-width', '300px');
```

Comment: I think this worked. I say think, because when I run the program, it works for a split second and then instantly reverts. There is a possibility, that somewhere else in the code, my friend set the size of the boxes (it's a colab) and I don't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the issue, though I still have no clue what is causing it.
I was going through things, and when I remove this piece of code, it works.
'document.documentElement.style.cssText = "--top-bar-color: #313440"'
Edit: I switched it to  'document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--top-bar-color","#313440")'
And it worked. Thanks for helping

Comment: Setting the cssText as a whole would override all styles already applied to the element, so  that's likely what was happening there.